# How to stop converting "greater than" and "less than" symbols to entities in TinyMCE?

Tags: html, tinymce-4

for some reasons I need to save the > and < symbols AS IS in my TinyMCE 4.2.2 editor instance.

I know I can set the entity_encoding to raw but, while this option prevent most symbols to be translated to entities, "greater than" and "less than" always get converted to `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Does anyone knows if a special flag or option is available for that?

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks Quentin for the fix in my text. :)

Comment: If you are storing it in a database then you need to replace the `&lt;` with `<` using functions like String.Replace and do not encode it on the server.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion man_luck. I know I can do that but it feels wrong to have to "fix" the entities for my needs when I can have it right straight from the tap... using CK 4 I can add a configuration to totally disable the convertions but It looks like a similar behaviour is not available in TinyMCE. :(

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact question since I want to treat the content of the TinyMCE editor as XML that possibly contains child elements. So if there's a `<sub>3</sub>` in the editor field, I want to treat that as an XML element, not just some text. Anyway, this is something that TinyMCE just doesn't allow for. The TinyMCE 4.x docs state several times that:

> The base entities < > & ' and " will always be entity encoded into their named equivalents. Though ' and " will only be encoded within attribute values and < > will only be encoded within text nodes. This is correct according to the HTML and XML specifications.

See [here](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#entities) and [here](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#entity_encoding). There's also some old discussion [here](http://community.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=18339) about this on the TinyMCE help forums.

The conclusion is that TinyMCE does not allow you to get unescaped less-than or greater-than symbols so you must convert them back from HTML entity codes after you get the text back from TinyMCE.